# Generating the SHA hash of a string using golang

Tags: hash, go

Can someone show me a working example of how to generate a SHA hash of a string that I have, say `myPassword := "beautiful"`, using Go?

Comment: If password hashing is actually what you're doing, you should not be using bare SHA1 for this - use PBKDF2, SCRYPT, or BCRYPT.

Comment: Yes, I would like to do any of that. But golang does not support any of them natively and I don't want to rely on third party libraries.

Comment: Relying on a third party library is infinitely better than using unsalted, un-iterated SHA1 just because it's available.

Comment: @dystroy The issue is not the strength of SHA1; it's the lack of a salt and key stretching. Adding a salt alone is insufficient, too - you should use an algorithm that iterates.

Comment: You're right to point the risks of just using sha1 but are we talking about the last theoretical attack possibilities or the basic reality? SHA1 attacks won't be a thing before a long time and SHA 256 is strong enough (with a salt) for most usages.

Comment: I am using sha512 fwiw. But after reading about rainbow attacks etc., I am not too convinced about storing password hash at all. BCRYPT seems to be a better option. But what I am doing is mainly for a experimental personal project. So not much to worry about security :-) thanks for your comments.

Comment: FYI, brcypt for Go is available [here](http://go.pkgdoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.crypto/bcrypt).

Comment: @Mostafa thank you a lot. I have some outdated version and it didn't had it. now updating.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

An example :

```
import (
    "crypto/sha1"
    "encoding/base64"
)

func (ms *MapServer) storee(bv []byte) {
    hasher := sha1.New()
    hasher.Write(bv)
    sha := base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString(hasher.Sum(nil))
        ...
}
```

In this example I make a sha from a byte array. You can get the byte array using

```
bv := []byte(myPassword)
```

Of course you don't need to encode it in base64 if you don't have to : you may use the raw byte array returned by the Sum function.

There seems to be some little confusion in comments below. So let's clarify for next users the best practices on conversions to strings:

- you never store a SHA as a string in a database, but as raw bytes
- when you want to display a SHA to a user, a common way is [Hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal)
- when you want a string representation because it must fit in an URL or in a filename, the usual solution is [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), which is more compact

Comment: The usual way to represent a sha as a string is hex encoding not base64.

Comment: Depends on your need. Hex encoding is good for humans but even heavier than base64. If you want to store your hash in a db, or send it in json, or use it as a file name (as in my example), I think base64 is better.

Comment: @DenysSéguret if you're going to store it in a db then it might be best just to store the bytes since db contents generally shouldn't be stored encoded

Comment: @BrianLeishman In my answer I explicitly says *"you never store a SHA as a string in a database, but as raw bytes"*

Comment: @DenysSéguret Ah my bad, I was replying to your comment "If you want to store your hash in a db ... base64 is better"

Comment: @BrianLeishman Yes, I see this comment may be confusing. I won't even try to guess what exactly I was explaining here 6 years ago ^^

Answer (score 92):

[Go By Example](https://gobyexample.com/sha1-hashes) has a page on sha1 hashing.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "crypto/sha1"
    "encoding/hex"
)

func main() {

    s := "sha1 this string"
    h := sha1.New()
    h.Write([]byte(s))
    sha1_hash := hex.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil))

    fmt.Println(s, sha1_hash)
}
```

You can [run this example on play.golang.org](http://play.golang.org/p/dPr9lt1uIS)

Answer (score 28):

The package documentation at http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/sha1/ does have an example that demonstrates this.  It's stated as an example of the New function, but it's the only example on the page and it has a link right near the top of the page so it is worth looking at.  The complete example is,

> Code:

```
h := sha1.New()
io.WriteString(h, "His money is twice tainted: 'taint yours and 'taint mine.")
fmt.Printf("% x", h.Sum(nil))
```

> Output:
>
> 59 7f 6a 54 00 10 f9 4c 15 d7 18 06 a9 9a 2c 87 10 e7 47 bd

Comment: It does. Seems like it is so hard to find with so many hidden parts. Usability issue.

Comment: @SankarP : For now, especially if you don't program in Go every day, it's a little hard to understand how to use the API. I found it easier to read the API source code (which is generally simple). It will probably be easier with time and more online third parties examples and docs.

Comment: @SankarP: Try [godock.org](http://godock.org) for easier standard library api navigation.

Comment: `h.Write([]byte("some string")` is more concise than your given example using `WriteString`

Answer (score 23):

You can actually do this in a much more concise and idiomatic manner:

```
// Assuming 'r' is set to some inbound net/http request
form_value := []byte(r.PostFormValue("login_password"))
sha1_hash := fmt.Sprintf("%x", sha1.Sum(form_value))

// Then output optionally, to test
fmt.Println(sha1_hash)
```

In this trivial example of a [http.Request](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request) POST containing a login_password field, it is worth noting that [fmt.Sprintf()](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf) called with `%x` converted the hash value to hex without having to include an `import "encoding/hex"` declaration.

( We used [fmt.Sprintf()](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf) as opposed to [fmt.Printf()](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Printf) as we were outputting a string to a variable assignment, not an [io.Writer](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer) interface. )

Also of reference, is that the [sha1.Sum()](http://golang.org/src/crypto/sha1/sha1.go?s=2235:2267#L115) function verbosely instantiates in the same manner as the [sha1.New()](http://golang.org/src/crypto/sha1/sha1.go?s=900:920#L41) definition:

```
func New() hash.Hash {
    d := new(digest)
    d.Reset()
    return d
}

func Sum(data []byte) [Size]byte {
    var d digest
    d.Reset()
    d.Write(data)
    return d.checkSum()
}
```

This holds true ( at least at the time of posting ) for the Sha library variants in Golang's standard crypto set, such as [Sha512](http://golang.org/src/crypto/sha512/sha512.go).

Lastly, if one wanted to, they could follow Golang's [to]String() implementation with something like `func (h hash.Hash) String() string {...}` to encapsulate the process.

That is most likely beyond the desired scope of the original question.

Comment: Thanks for all the extra detail Mr. Webster!

Answer (score 12):

```golang
h := sha1.New()
h.Write(content)
sha := h.Sum(nil)  // "sha" is uint8 type, encoded in base16

shaStr := hex.EncodeToString(sha)  // String representation

fmt.Printf("%x\n", sha)
fmt.Println(shaStr)
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's some good examples:

- http://golang.org/src/pkg/crypto/hmac/hmac_test.go
- http://www.jokecamp.com/blog/examples-of-creating-base64-hashes-using-hmac-sha256-in-different-languages/#go

The second example targets sha256, to do sha1 hexadecimal you'd do:

```
// Calculate the hexadecimal HMAC SHA1 of requestDate using sKey                
key := []byte(c.SKey)                                                           
h := hmac.New(sha1.New, key)                                                    
h.Write([]byte(requestDate))                                                    
hmacString := hex.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil))
```

(from https://github.com/soniah/dnsmadeeasy)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a function you could use to generate a SHA1 hash:

```
// SHA1 hashes using sha1 algorithm
func SHA1(text string) string {
    algorithm := sha1.New()
    algorithm.Write([]byte(text))
    return hex.EncodeToString(algorithm.Sum(nil))
}
```

I put together a group of those utility hash functions here: https://github.com/shomali11/util

You will find `FNV32`, `FNV32a`, `FNV64`, `FNV65a`, `MD5`, `SHA1`, `SHA256` and `SHA512`

Answer (score 3):

As a one liner hashing in Go is more convenient:

```golang
sha := sha256.Sum256([]byte())
```

The result is a `[]byte` and might be transformed into hex or base64.

Answer (score 2):

```
// Get sha1 from string
func Hashstr(Txt string) string {
    h := sha1.New()
    h.Write([]byte(Txt))
    bs  := h.Sum(nil)
    sh:= string(fmt.Sprintf("%x\n", bs))
    return sh
}
```

Comment: Speed and useful.