# How to calculate sha256 file checksum in Go

Tags: file, io, cryptography, go, sha256

I need utility for Windows that calculates sha256 file checksum so that when I download
fedora I can verify checksum from here: https://fedoraproject.org/static/checksums/Fedora-18-i386-CHECKSUM

Microsoft utility from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/889768 does only md5 and sha1.

I don't want to use other downloadable tools that are not signed and not available from https or from sources that I don't know about, because it does not make any sense to download unsigned code over unencrypted connection or from untrusted source to verify signature of another code to trust it.

Luckily google provides possibility to use https for all downloads so I can download Go over secure connection and start from there.

Here is simple code that does that for a small file, but it's not very good for big files because it's not streaming.

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "crypto/sha256"
    "os"
    "log"
    "encoding/hex"
)

func main() {
    hasher := sha256.New()
    s, err := ioutil.ReadFile(os.Args[1])    
    hasher.Write(s)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    os.Stdout.WriteString(hex.EncodeToString(hasher.Sum(nil)))
}
```

How to make it to use streams so that it works on any file size.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating the SHA hash of a string using golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10701874/generating-the-sha-hash-of-a-string-using-golang)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The SHA256 hasher implements the `io.Writer` interface, so one option would be to use the `io.Copy()` function to copy the data from an appropriate `io.Reader` in blocks.  Something like this should do:

```
f, err := os.Open(os.Args[1])
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer f.Close()
if _, err := io.Copy(hasher, f); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Comment: do I need to do `sha256.New()` if I'm doing this in a loop?

Comment: @majidarif: you can reuse the hasher by calling its `Reset` method.  If you don't reset and start calculating the hash of a second file, you'll instead be calculating the hash of the two files concatenated.  With that said, your code will probably be more readable if you don't try to reuse the hashers.

Comment: How does *io.Copy* work? Is the file read entirely in memory or is it processed by chunks... of size?

Comment: @Massimo: in the generic case, it will use a 32 kB buffer to copy data in chunks.  As the documentation states, it will defer to the `src.WriteTo` or `dest.ReadFrom` methods if they exist.  Those may have different buffering behaviours, but shouldn't read the entire file.

Comment: there is also an entire library dedicated to this, even if it seems an overkill to me 
https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/udhos/equalfile#pkg-functions

Answer (score 43):

The [crypto/sha256 godoc](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/sha256) actually has a [snippet](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/sha256/#New) that shows how to do that (it's basically the same code as James):

```
package main

import (
  "crypto/sha256"
  "fmt"
  "io"
  "log"
  "os"
)

func main() {
  f, err := os.Open("file.txt")
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
  defer f.Close()

  h := sha256.New()
  if _, err := io.Copy(h, f); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }

  fmt.Printf("%x", h.Sum(nil))
}
```

Comment: How does *io.Copy* work? Is the file read entirely in memory or is it processed by chunks... of size?

Comment: It's processed by chunks of 32KB: https://golang.org/src/io/io.go#L380 You can change that by providing your own buffer using CopyBuffer

Comment: should I generate the sha256 hash only once as a global var or is it needed a new one before each comparison?

Answer (score 11):

Full example of md5sum:

```
func md5sum(filePath string) (string, error) {
    file, err := os.Open(filePath)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    defer file.Close()

    hash := md5.New()
    if _, err := io.Copy(hash, file); err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    return hex.EncodeToString(hash.Sum(nil)), nil
}
```

`EncodeToString` does not omits leading 0 bytes, so `fmt.Println(hex.EncodeToString([]byte{0x00, 0x00, 0xA, 0xB, 0xC}))` gives
`00000a0b0c`