# How to generate aes key with SHA1PRNG algorithm in golang?

Tags: go

Forgive my pool English.
The server program is code by java, i need to send it a password to generate aes key.The password is a random bytes array. The server program use the password as random seed to generate a 128 bits AES key with SHA1PRNG algorithm. The same password with gen the same key.
Now i am coding the client program with golang. How to generate the AES key with a random bytes array in  golang?

Comment: Why would you add the encryption to the client?

Comment: did not get your question. I guess you are asking for this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10701874/generating-the-sha-hash-of-a-string-using-golang

Comment: I need to communicate with server with AES .

Comment: [crypto/rand.Read](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rand/#Read)

Answer (score 0):

you can try the code below

```
func SHA1(data []byte) []byte {
    h := sha1.New()
    h.Write(data)
    return h.Sum(nil)
}

func aesKeySecureRandom(keyword string) (key []byte) {
    data := []byte(keyword)

    hashs := SHA1(SHA1(data))
    key = hashs[0:16]

    return key
}
```

you can use java or golang to verify

example:

keyword:123456

plainText:abc111abc

key hex:6bb4837eb74329105ee4568dda7dc67e

key base64:a7SDfrdDKRBe5FaN2n3Gfg==

cipherText base64:7ke0HhU5KnkCaPBilYsMiw==